# Drives under /media/user/ are denoted by an alphanumeric string - how are they generated?

Tags: linux, mount, usb-drive, automounting, uuid

I noticed that my thumb drives and hard drivers are in the location /media/user and are denoted as a string of alphabets and numbers instead of their names such as 1A2B-3C4D. I never named my drives to such strings. How are they generated? Are the strings unique? Is there a possibility that two different drives can have the same identifier?

Answer (score 3):

If *volume label* is set, that uses volume label of the file system. If it doesn't have a label, it uses *UUID* (or *serial number*) of the file system, whatever that means.

It is the same UUID that you also see with `lsblk` and can use in `fstab`, for example.

By default it is randomly assigned during file system creation, but you can supply your own. There could be unlikely case when they happen to be the same, especially for short numbers such as FAT uses (32 bit). If you plug two devices with the same UUID or the same label into the machine, `udisks` (or whatever automounter your system uses) will append something to the directory name for the second mounted one to make them different.

For FAT, you can use `fatlabel` from `dosfstools` to change the volume label and also to work on the serial.